# Visual Studio 2022 Mac - Cannot Switch Branch - Repository has no signature

Tags: visual-studio

I Have a problem switching to a local branch in visual studio 2022 for mac, it shows error that repository has no signature. It makes this error on a project cloned from GitLab and a project cloned from GitHub.

[image: 1]